# app crashes while performing logging out routines

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, facebook-ios-sdk

Receiving the following message after trying to log out from my app:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'MainMenuSegue'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'**

Though it only happens after I've logged in my app through Facebook login.

Here's a link to an [image](http://i61.tinypic.com/14npa2s.png) of my Storyboard. Sorry I couldn't put it directly in Stack Over Flow. In the Image you'll see the segues and the Navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear. You're calling `MainMenuSegue`, which is a *push* segue. But the controller calling it isn't managed by a navigation controller. So there's no navigation stack to push the new view controller on to.

Don't use a push segue… or embed the source controller in a navigation controller.

Comment: To add to Aaron's answer, add an Exception Breakpoint in your project so that it will (hopefully) stop at the line where you're calling this push segue.

Comment: Hi Aaron, in the image of the storyboard I've just added to the question, does the controller calling been managed by a navigation controller?

Comment: I don't know which controller is calling the segue.